# Including a hash param in Rails URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I have links on a page which go to `pages_path('index')`. 
That works fine, only I want each link to go to a specific section of a page.

So each link would look something like

`www.example.com/pages/index#locations`

Right now I'm using a rather hacky solution to generate this link

`link_to "About", "#{page_path('index')}#about"`

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `anchor` option:

```
link_to "About", page_path('index', anchor: "about")
```